# Matlab+ Graph theory+ weight assignment

Tags: matlab, graph-theory

I have been trying to label the edges of an undirected graph, also, i am using this matgraph tool! I succeeded in making a graph, i just want to assign weights to it... Please help!!

Here is what i tried,

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;
g=graph;
for k=1:6

add(g,k,k+1)
add(g,1,4)
add(g,5,7)
end
ndraw(g);
x=rand(1,1);
y=rand(1,1)
A =[0 x 0 x 0 0 0;
x 0 x 0 0 0 0;
0 x 0 x 0 0 0;
x 0 x 0 x 0 0;
0 0 0 y 0 x x;
0 0 0 0 x 0 x;
0 0 0 0 x x 0]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you can add this code after the code you wrote:

```
% get line info from the figure
lineH = findobj(gca, 'type', 'line');
xData = cell2mat(get(lineH, 'xdata')); % get x-data
yData = cell2mat(get(lineH, 'ydata')); % get y-data

% if an edge is between (x1,y1)<->(x2,y2), place a label at
% the center of the line, i.e. (x1+x2)/2 (y1+y2)/2 etc
labelposx=mean(xData');
labelposy=mean(yData');

% generate some random weights vector
weights=randi(21,length(labelposx),1); 

% plot the weights on top of the figure
text(labelposx,labelposy,mat2cell(weights), 'HorizontalAlignment','center',... 
                                            'BackgroundColor',[.7 .9 .7]);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks nate!!! I have been trying to do this since a day..... I am very much new to matlab, and WOULD WANT TO KNOW, HOW TO GET AN ADJACENCY MATRIX OUT OF THIS?!

Comment: it is considered impolite to write in CAPITAL LETTERS!
The adjacency matrix of a graph is returned by matrix(g). This returns a square logical matrix. To use this matrix arithmetically, convert it to class double; for example, the following command returns the eigenvalues of (the adjacency matrix of) a graph:
eig(double(matrix(g)))
Conversely, given a square, symmetric, zero-one, zero-diagonal matrix A, we can set g to have this matrix as its adjacency matrix like this: set_matrix(g,A). See also spy, laplacian, and incidence_matrix. (see http://www.ams.jhu.edu/~ers/matgraph/matgraph.pdf )

Comment: Oh, i am sorry for writing in capital letters, ignorant me!!!
nate, thank you so much for the help!!! this helps a lot! Thank you, immensely!!!

Comment: nate, I am having a problem in matlab in assigning weights such that the (weights coming at every node from its edges+ its own weight) adds upto one